# Pyramid: root context path

Tags: python, pyramid

I am new to python. I deployed my web application in

```
 http://localhost/myapp/
```

How can I extract the context root from the pyramid request object.

PS: In java  [HttpServletRequest#getContextPath](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath()) will give me the root path.

Is there any similar function available in python pyramid.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using "root", "context" and "path" in some Java-esque sense which may be unfamiliar to most people working with Pyramid :)

Anyway, most likely the answer to your question can be found in the documentation for the Pytamid's [request object](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/docs/pyramid/en/latest/api/request.html) (see `root`, `subpath`, `traversed`, `virtual_root`, `virtual_root_path`) or in the [Virtual Hosting](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/docs/pyramid/en/latest/narr/vhosting.html#vhosting-chapter) chapter of the docs.